# How to find an image and get path in twig generated content

Tags: php, twig

I am a newbie to PHP Symfony and Twig. I need to dynamically set meta property og:image from the post content, if there is an image. I have a twig code like this.

```
<div class="content">
{{ d.description|raw }}
</div>
```

I can and get an image url from the div content if any and set it as a meta property og:image by using javascript but Facebook does not parse JavaScript? Is there a way to do this on server side?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please take the habit to share what you already tried, it could help us narrow down the problem and allow us to provide more precise code. I've tried a general answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook indeed only reads the source code of the page, so you won't be able to js your way out of it, you have to rely on server side.

You'd have to process the content, in the controller, by using a DOM parser (you can use PHP's own DOMDocument class https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and search for an img node (or lack thereof, in case you'll need to provide a default value)

Once you have found the url of the src of the image (user provided or default), pass this as a variable to the view and echo it inside the appropriate `meta` tag.

Do not forget to print the full path of the image, including the domain and protocol as Facebook now requires it.